# Why won’t CouchDB allow me to use a mounted drive as a storage location?

Tags: linux, config, couchdb

I have a GCP VM that has CouchdB installed. I’m trying to use Fusion to mount a storage bucket on to the VM. My problem is that when I change the CouchDB config file and point the DB file path to the mounted drive, CouchDB fails to start. I’ve tried changing the permissions, but nothing works.

Below are the two lines of the config file:

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = %localstatelibdir%
view_index_dir = %localstatelibdir%
```